# Linux: Read raw HID data

Tags: linux, driver

I am trying to write a driver for a gamecontroller, which is already recognized as a "hidraw" by linux. I searched the webs and came across this example:

https://github.com/atomic-penguin/linux/blob/master/samples/hidraw/hid-example.c

If i compile and run it, I get the following output:

```
Report Descriptor Size: 203
Report Descriptor:
5 1 15 0 9 4 a1 1 85 30 5 1 5 9 19 1 29 a 15 0 25 1 75 1 95 a 55 0 65 0 81 2 5 9 19 b 29 e 15 0 25 1 75 1 95 4 81 2 75 1 95 2 81 3 b 1 0 1 0 a1 0 b 30 0 1 0 b 31 0 1 0 b 32 0 1 0 b 35 0 1 0 15 0 27 ff ff 0 0 75 10 95 4 81 2 c0 b 39 0 1 0 15 0 25 7 35 0 46 3b 1 65 14 75 4 95 1 81 2 5 9 19 f 29 12 15 0 25 1 75 1 95 4 81 2 75 8 95 34 81 3 6 0 ff 85 21 9 1 75 8 95 3f 81 3 85 81 9 2 75 8 95 3f 81 3 85 1 9 3 75 8 95 3f 91 83 85 10 9 4 75 8 95 3f 91 83 85 80 9 5 75 8 95 3f 91 83 85 82 9 6 75 8 95 3f 91 83 c0 

Raw Name: Nintendo Co., Ltd. Pro Controller
Raw Phys: usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
Raw Info:
    bustype: 3 (USB)
    vendor: 0x057e
    product: 0x2009
ioctl HIDIOCGFEATURE returned: 4
HIDIOCGFEATURE: Broken pipe
write() wrote 2 bytes
read: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And here I'm stuck. How can I make sense of the report descriptor? And more inportantly: Why is the read() operation failing? (It returns -1).
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I got the same problem with another device and I am stuck at the same point. Did you got any further?

Comment: I ended up using a library called hidapi, maybe that'll help you as well.

Comment: I think what's happening is exactly what it tells you. You probably opened the file in non-blocking mode. That error means there's nothing to read at the moment. The proper way would be using `poll` or `select` to wait for data ready. ...or you could just keep reading until you get something.